# Does this inequality hold true?

Tags: inequality, summation, real-numbers, integers

I am having some trouble proving (or finding a counterexample) the following inequality:

Let $C = \{c_1, c_2,...,c_k\}$ be a finite sequence of positive integers. Also, let $V = \{v_1, v_2,...,v_k\}$ be a sequence of positive real numbers. Then, I want to show that: $$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^kv_i}{k^2} \geq \frac{\sum_{i=1}^kc_iv_i}{\left(\sum_{i=1}^kc_i\right)^2}$$

Is this inequality true? If yes, then how do I prove it? And if no, what is a counterexample?

Comment: Are $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ *positive* real numbers? Otherwise we can always reverse the signs,$$(v_1,\ldots,v_k) \mapsto (-v_1,\ldots,-v_k),$$ to reverse the direction of inequality.

Comment: This vaguely resembles Titu's lemma and Cauchy-Schwartz.

Comment: @SangchulLee Oh yes its always positive. Let me edit that.

Comment: I think that square power is a red flag

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assume that the inequality holds for any $c_1, \ldots, c_k \in \mathbb{N}_1$ and $v_1, \ldots, v_k \in (0, \infty)$. Then by letting $v_1 = 1$ and $v_i \to 0^+$ for each $i = 2, \ldots, k$, we find that

$$ \frac{1}{k^2} \geq \frac{c_1}{(\sum_{i=1}^{k} c_i )^2}, \qquad\text{or equivalently,} \qquad \biggl(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{k} c_i}{k} \biggr)^2 \geq c_1. $$

However, by choosing $c_1 = 2$ and $c_2 = \ldots = c_k = 1$, this reduces to

$$ \left(1 + \frac{1}{k}\right)^2 \geq 2, $$

which is false if $k$ is large enough, a contradiction! Therefore the inequality is false.

For a concrete counter-example, consider:

$$ \left\{ \begin{gathered}
k = 3, \\
(c_1, c_2, c_3) = (2, 1, 1), \\
(v_1, v_2, v_3) = (1, \tfrac{1}{10}, \tfrac{1}{10})
\end{gathered} \right\}
\qquad\implies\qquad
\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{k} v_i}{k^2}
= \frac{2}{15}
< \frac{11}{80}
= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{k} c_i v_i}{(\sum_{i=1}^{k} c_i )^2}. $$